# regularexpression for this text sql statement or a program?

Tags: sql, regex, sqlplus

Heres specifically the sql text in a file.

```
   select substr(to_char(ctl.tody_run_dt,'YYYYMMDD'),1,8) tody_yyyymmdd,           
        substr(to_char(cdr.nxt_proc_dt,'YYYYMMDD'),1,8) nxt_proc_yyyymmdd,       
        add_months(ctl.tody_run_dt - cdr.past_accru_dys,                         
              - ct.nbr_cycl_for_adj) beg_proc_dt,                           
                from tbl_crd )                                                         
      and prv.calendar_run_dt =                                                    
       ( select max(calendar_run_dt)                                              
      from run_tbl1 prv2
```

From this i wish to extract all the tables,
This seems pretty complicated to be done through a regexp? Is there a way? Or should i write a program? I just cant come up with an algorithm.

Comment: I don't think this can be done with a regexp. The parsing is more complicated.

Comment: Regexp is not able to process this kind of statement. You could use it only for guessing the table names, but you could always get column names, server names all kinds of identifiers. The correct way is to parse this statement with already available parsers like JSqlParser for java and then get from the parse tree the names you want.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do something like a linear search like this. It relaxed for your example
and just targets the `from` keyword, excludes other keywords.

The table data is captured in group 1. It has to be split appart upon each
match through the find loop.

```
 #  from\s+((?!(?:select|from|where|and)\b)\w+(?:[,\s]+(?!(?:select|from|where|and)\b)\w+)*)

 from 
 \s+ 
 (                # (1 start), Contains all the table info
      (?!              # exclude keywords
           (?:
                select
             |  from
             |  where
             |  and 
           )
           \b 
      )
      \w+ 
      (?:
           [,\s]+          
           (?!              # exclude keywords
                (?:
                     select 
                  |  from
                  |  where
                  |  and 
                )
                \b 
           )
           \w+ 
      )*
 )                # (1 end)
```

Perl test case

```
$/ = undef;

$str = <DATA>;

while ( $str =~ /from\s+((?!(?:select|from|where|and)\b)\w+(?:[,\s]+(?!(?:select|from|where|and)\b)\w+)*)/g )
{
     print "\n'$1'";
}

__DATA__
   select substr(to_char(ctl.tody_run_dt,'YYYYMMDD'),1,8) tody_yyyymmdd,
        substr(to_char(cdr.nxt_proc_dt,'YYYYMMDD'),1,8) nxt_proc_yyyymmdd,
        add_months(ctl.tody_run_dt - cdr.past_accru_dys,
              - ct.nbr_cycl_for_adj) beg_proc_dt,
       (ctl.tody_run_dt + cdr.futr_accru_dys) end_proc_dt,
     ctl.tody_end_proc_dt,
   ctl.prv_end_proc_dt,
   cdr.fst_proc_dy,
   cdr.lst_proc_dy,
   cdr.accru_nbr_of_dys,
   cdr.dy_of_wk,
        from run_tbl1 cdr, runtbl
       run_tbl1 prv,
       run_tbl_cntl ctl,
       tbl_crd ct
       where cdr.calendar_run_dt = ctl.tody_run_dt
      and ct.nbr_cycl_for_adj =
      ( select max(nbr_cycl_for_adj)

       from tbl_crd )
      and prv.calendar_run_dt =
       ( select max(calendar_run_dt)
      from run_tbl1 prv2
      where prv2.calendar_run_dt < ctl.tody_run_dt
       and prv2.accru_nbr_of_dys = 1 )
       and rownum = 1
```

Output >>

```
'run_tbl1 cdr, runtbl
       run_tbl1 prv,
       run_tbl_cntl ctl,
       tbl_crd ct'
'tbl_crd'
'run_tbl1 prv2'
```

Answer (score 0):

First I had to correct some syntax errors within your SQL.

```
... cdr.dy_of_wk,  <<<< the comma is wrong
    from run_tbl1 cdr ...
```

Here the proove of concept using JSQLParser V0.8.9 (https://github.com/JSQLParser/JSqlParser) to extract tablenames.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JSQLParserException {
    TablesNamesFinder tfinder = new TablesNamesFinder();
    String sql = "select substr(to_char(ctl.tody_run_dt,'YYYYMMDD'),1,8) tody_yyyymmdd, "
            + " substr(to_char(cdr.nxt_proc_dt,'YYYYMMDD'),1,8) nxt_proc_yyyymmdd, "
            + " add_months(ctl.tody_run_dt - cdr.past_accru_dys, "
            + " - ct.nbr_cycl_for_adj) beg_proc_dt, "
            + " (ctl.tody_run_dt + cdr.futr_accru_dys) end_proc_dt, "
            + " ctl.tody_end_proc_dt,  "
            + " ctl.prv_end_proc_dt,  "
            + " cdr.fst_proc_dy,  "
            + " cdr.lst_proc_dy,  "
            + " cdr.accru_nbr_of_dys,  "
            + " cdr.dy_of_wk  "
            + " from run_tbl1 cdr, runtbl,  "
            + " run_tbl1 prv,  "
            + " run_tbl_cntl ctl,  "
            + " tbl_crd ct  "
            + " where cdr.calendar_run_dt = ctl.tody_run_dt  "
            + " and ct.nbr_cycl_for_adj =  "
            + " ( select max(nbr_cycl_for_adj)  "
            + " from tbl_crd )  "
            + " and prv.calendar_run_dt =  "
            + " ( select max(calendar_run_dt)  "
            + " from run_tbl1 prv2  "
            + " where prv2.calendar_run_dt < ctl.tody_run_dt "
            + " and prv2.accru_nbr_of_dys = 1 )  "
            + " and rownum = 1 ";

    //parse SQL statement
    Select select = (Select) CCJSqlParserUtil.parse(sql);
    //extract table names
    List<String> tableList = tfinder.getTableList(select);

    System.out.println(tableList);
}
```

and it outputs

```
[run_tbl1, runtbl, run_tbl_cntl, tbl_crd]
```